# Не работает min-width на локальном сервере

Tags: php, html, css

Если запустить файл локально на компьютере через обычную HTML страничку. Все отлично работает и проблем не возникает.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Запущенный на локальном сервере:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Пробовал свойства **min-width and screen** ,**min-width and all**, **min-width**.
Свойство **max-width** на локальном сервере исправно работает

Comment: на иконочку мышку наводил? что пишет?

Comment: Недопустимое значение свойства.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том, что нет пробела перед плюсом и после плюса. Если их сделать, то будет работать

Comment: СПАСИБО. Как то странно что на сервере пробелы убирались!!!